# Jquery not send post link after submit form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends this is my code the code is working the form is submit then after the post link is not send please help.

```
$(function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
       $("#pitch_image_path_form").attr("id","pitch_image_path_formliveset");
            $("#pitch_image_path_formliveset")[0].submit(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                event.preventDefault();
                   alert("call");
            $.post("submit_investorform.php",{'flage':'getallimagesfromselectedid','form':'pitch_image_path_form'},function(result){
                $("#pitch_image_path_showalldatafromid").html(result);
            });
          });
         });

      });
```

Thank you

Comment: What's the [0] for? Why are you wrapping a .live event with `$(function(){`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear Rock Developer please try this code. this is help fully for me.

```
$("#pitch_image_path_browseiser").live("change",function(){
    $("#pitch_image_path_form").ajaxSubmit({ success: function(){ 
            $.post("submit_investorform.php",{'flage':'getallimagesfromselectedid','form':'pitch_image_path_form'},function(result){
                    $("#pitch_image_path_showalldatafromid").html(result);
                });
     } });
});
```

please check this link this is tutorial.

```
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
```